# How do I use the windows service and WCF to update some record in database?

Tags: wcf, service, tcp, windows-services, wcfserviceclient

I wrote a **wcf service** and then Host wcf in a **windows service** Using **TCP**.and then using the command **Installutil WindowsServiceSendMail.exe** register it on **windows 7**.

My problem is that the service does not start when i right click on the **service1**(on the window services on windows 7) and click start.
i read this [article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649818.aspx#_Objectives) and I went forward step by step But The result did not receive.

this is RunProgram() method in **wcf project** in solution

```
 [OperationContract]
  void RunProgram();

public void RunProgram()
{
  //code for check database
}
```

this is code  in **windows service project** in solution

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
    if (myServiceHost != null)
    {
        myServiceHost.Close();
    }
    myServiceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(Service1));
    myServiceHost.Open();
}

protected override void OnStop()
{
    if (myServiceHost != null)
    {
        myServiceHost.Close();
        myServiceHost = null;
    }
}
```

and then i add a reference from **wcf projec**t to **windows service project**

and then using the command **Installutil WindowsServiceSendMail.exe** register it on windows 7

you can download project from [here](http://www.mediafire.com/download/p17047u0y276uv1/WcfSendMail.rar)

My problem is that the service does not start when i right click on the **service1**(on the window services on windows 7) and click start.

Comment: There is not enough information to give you an answer.   Did you see an error?  Have you checked the event viewer?

Comment: event viewer in windows?

Answer (score 0):

I've found the problem. I changed the OnStart method.

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
    if (myServiceHost != null)
    {
        myServiceHost.Close();
    }
    myServiceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(SendMailService));
    myServiceHost.Open();

    WcfSendMail.SendMailServiceWCF s = new WcfSendMail.SendMailServiceWCF();
    s.RunProgram();
}
```

and **publish** windows service project and **run the setup.exe** in publish folder.
Of course using the command **Installutil WindowsServiceSendMail.exe** register it on windows 7.

Comment: Your solution doesn't make sense.  It looks like your creating an instance of the service directly and calling the `RunProgram` method.   If your intent is to host the WCF service in the Windows Service, simply opening an instance of the `ServiceHost` is sufficient - the client will send the requests to the service.